# Conceptualizing set comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, set, set-comprehension

```
def nfa_eclosure(M, s):
    """
    >>> M = [{'':{1,2,3}}, {'b':{1}}, {'a':{2}}]
    >>> nfa_eclosure(M, 0)
    set([0, 1, 2, 3])
    """
    try:
        states = {nfa_eclosure(M, x+1) for x in xrange(len(M[s])) if M[s].get('')}
    except IndexError:
        states = set([])
    states.add(s)
    return states
```

Running this throws `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`but I can't see the problem.

---

Edit: 2014-02-03 15:25:00

Thanks for the explanations everyone. That makes sense. Is there a "pythonic" way to take the code I have now and "splat" the contents of a set into a new set, rather than convert everything to a frozenset and then flatten it?

---

Edit: 2014-02-04 00:41:00

I made some modifications and now I came up with this:

```
try:
    return set([s]).union(*(nfa_eclosure(M, x) for x in M[s].get('')))
except IndexError:
    return set([s])
```

but I have a new error message

```
TypeError: union() argument after * must be a sequence, not generator
```

A google search didn't exactly explain the situation too well. Know what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to build a `set` of `set`s, recursively. This is not allowed because `set`s are `unhashable` and therefore cannot be placed in a `set`. You can use a `frozenset` because they *are* hashable.

```
try:
    states = frozenset({nfa_eclosure(M, x+1) for x in xrange(len(M[s])) if M[s].get('')})
except IndexError:
    states = frozenset([])
```

`set`s are unordered, precisely because they are ordered internally by the hash of their members. This allows for fast lookup of set members.

Read up on the docs for [sets](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) and [hashable](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make a set of sets. This won't work, because a set is not a hashable type, as it is mutable, and sets can only contain hashable types. This is because Python uses the hashes of items in a set to quickly check for membership.

You might able to use a `frozenset` instead. Failing that, try a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I'll get to accepting an answer shortly. Just wanted to explain the other issue I was having. [Apparently](http://bugs.python.org/issue13904) the error I was seeing with `TypeError` was a bug. Upon closer inspection, I was trying to iterate of NoneType with the given key didn't exist for the dictionary. I set the default to `set([])` and now everything runs as expected. Didn't end up going with the frozen set, but thanks for explaining it! I was so confused.